# Find the Jacobian of F

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, we define: $$F:\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} = \left\| Ax-b \right\|^2$$
Find the Jacobian of $F$, and show that it is of the form $\widetilde { A } x=\widetilde { b }$ where $\widetilde { A }$ and $\widetilde { b }$ are written explicitly in terms of  $A$ and $b$.

What I did was express $F$ of the form: $$F= \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j-b_i\right)^2 $$

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}F}{\operatorname{d}x_i} =2 a_{ii} x_i \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j-b_i\right)$$

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hint: $\|Ax-b\|^2 = (Ax-b)^T(Ax-b)$

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Yeah but how do you find the Jacobian of that? I cannot prevent from transforming F into explicit summations and that leads me nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x+h)=\lvert\lvert A(x+h)-b\rvert\rvert^{2}=((Ax-b)^{T}+h^{T}A^{T})((Ax-b)+Ah)$

$=(Ax-b)^{T}(Ax-b)+h^{T}A^{T}(Ax-b)+(Ax-b)^{T}Ah+h^{T}A^{T}Ah$

$=F(x)+2(Ax-b)^{T}Ah+\lvert\lvert Ah\rvert\rvert^{2}=F(x)+\underbrace{2(Ax-b)^{T}Ah}_{\text{first order}}+o(\lvert\lvert h\rvert\rvert)$

Comment: So what would ${ J }_{ F }^{ x }$ be?

Comment: @JKMath $2(Ax-b)^{T}A$. To be clear you were looking for the jacobian matrix of the function?

Comment: Correct. But then ${ J }_{ F }^{ x }=0$ Would only lead to Ax = b and not something of the form $\widetilde { A }x=\widetilde { b }$  where $\widetilde { A }$  and $\widetilde { b }$ are written explicitly in terms of A and b.

Comment: Setting $J_{F}^{x}=0$ we get that $2(Ax-b)^{T}A=0$. Taking transposes of both sides we have that: $0=2A^{T}(Ax-b)=2A^{T}Ax-A^{T}b$. So $A^{T}Ax=A^{T}b$.